# How to single query this case

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a timestamp as a parameter I call it "C".
And in the database I have a table "TABLE" which contains 2 fields. Timestamp "A", Timestamp "B".

I want to fetch rows from "TABLE" which is sorted by "A" that is **nearest** to "C" and hasn't passed "B" yet. How do I do that?

I know how to query the condition now() <= "B". But I can't do the sorting in a single query.
What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What exact DBMS is used?

Comment: and do you mean the single record?

Comment: @William: too late :-) I'm sure you could write postgresql specific query yourself :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you didn't say what database server you use, here is a tip:

```
WHERE timestamp_b >= current_timestamp
ORDER BY ABS(timestamp_c - timestamp_a)
```

This way you'll get the events that has `timestamp_b` that hasn't passed yet and ordered by the "closeness" to timestamp_a

Comment: Hahaha, how did I not think of that. Thank you!!

Comment: If you want to be "generic" (as in ANSI SQL) you should use `current_timestamp` instead of `now()`.

Comment: But in PostgreSQL now() is equivalent to current_timestamp?
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @William: according to the documentation page - yes.